# Passing multiple wildcard filenames to a command in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

Twice now during development with gcc on Windows, I've run into [perl](http://dlbeer.co.nz/oss/avstack.html) [scripts](http://www.gson.org/egypt/egypt.html) meant for Unix systems that take a list of >100 filenames as their argument, which I need to create using wildcards to select them out of a folder of many other files:

```
perl avstack.pl */*.o
perl egypt *.expand
```

But Windows doesn't do wildcard expansion, the command itself is required to do this.  How can I write a batch script to get the list of filenames and pass it to the program?  For example:

```
avstack.bat */*.o
egypt.bat *.expand
```

Or, since the file extensions are known for each batch file, it could be called with a folder name instead:

```
avstack.bat "C:\path\with\some_o_files"
egypt.bat "D:\path\with\some_expand_files"
```

(Actually the folder method would probably be better since I could make a drag-and-drop shortcut or SendTo menu item.)

Comment: Inside your batch file, use the `FOR` command to get a list of files within a folder.

Comment: @Squashman I've read many related questions and answers on here, but I can't figure out how to produce a single-line list of filenames and pass the whole list to a command as the argument

Answer (score 1):

This kind of works, based on https://superuser.com/a/460648/13889:

```
@echo off

cd "%~1"

set expanded_list=
for %%f in (*.expand) do call set expanded_list=%%expanded_list%% "%%f"

perl egypt %expanded_list% > egypt-output.txt
```